# Berry Phase of Topological Insulators

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-insulators, berry-pancharatnam-phase

I read all threads about that topic I could find, but didn't really find a sufficient answer for me, so I decided to ask my own:

I read in Bernevig's book "Topological Insulators and Topological Superconductors" that the Berry Phase of a system is computed via the Integral of the Berry curvature over the Brillouin zone and that it is quantized in units of 2pi. I see how that plays a role in Chern Insulators.
However, I also learned that in time-reversal symmetric systems, such as 3D TIs, the Chern index is zero because the Berry curvature vanishes (at least at the time reversal invariant momenta). I also understand that part and that the result is a Z2 Invariant in these systems. But still I read everywhere that 3D TIs come with a Berry Phase of pi. Are there two different definitions of the Berry Phase?

Coming from the calculation via the Berry curvature it is clear to me that the Berry phase is a multiple of 2pi and should be zero for time reversal symmetric systems. What am I missing?

Comment: I think what they mean is that for TRI TIs you can still have regions in the Brillouin zone where the Chern number does not vanish (locally) even though the total Chern number is zero.